# how to modify a received json file so that it is valid?

Tags: json, swift, string

I have been developing in swift for a short time and I come across a problem that I have not had before.
a website sends me the following json.

```
  {
    "nhits": 72,
    "parameters": {
        "dataset": "prix_des_carburants_j_7",
        "rows": 10,
        "start": 0,
        "refine": {
            "city": "MARSEILLE"
        },
        "format": "json",
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    "records": [
        {
            "datasetid": "prix_des_carburants_j_7",
            "recordid": "88d38c1f23cbef399630ca9a36cc4047ff1a2908",
            "fields": {
                "geo_point": [
                    43.31733,
                    5.43951
                ],
                "price_sp95": 1.594,
                "city": "MARSEILLE",
                "automate_24_24": "Non",
                "price_e10": 1.544,
                "timetable": "{\"Dimanche\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Jeudi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Lundi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Mardi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Mercredi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Samedi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Vendredi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}}",
                "services": "DAB (Distributeur automatique de billets)/Lavage automatique/Automate CB 24/24",
                "name": "SUPERMARCHÉ CARREFOUR MARKET",
                "brand": "Carrefour Market",
                "pop": "R",
                "cp": "13012",
                "id": "13012015",
                "fuel": "Gazole",
                "address": "7 Chemin des Amaryllis",
                "update": "2021-08-05T06:00:00+00:00",
                "price_gazole": 1.415
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    5.43951,
                    43.31733
                ]
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2021-08-05T06:00:00+00:00"
        },
        {
            "datasetid": "prix_des_carburants_j_7",
            "recordid": "f816da71ba0ff88030ebd2a104f100aef0b2a78b",
            "fields": {
                "geo_point": [
                    43.3177505955,
                    5.37430169143
                ],
                "city": "MARSEILLE",
                "price_e10": 1.57,
                "services": "Carburant additivé/Toilettes publiques/Boutique alimentaire/Station de gonflage/Services réparation/entretien/Vente de gaz domestique (Butane, Propane)/Piste poids lourds/Lavage automatique/Lavage manuel",
                "name": "AGIP MARSEILLE SAINTE MARTHE",
                "brand": "Agip",
                "pop": "R",
                "shortage": "SP95/E85/GPLc",
                "cp": "13014",
                "id": "13014008",
                "fuel": "Gazole/E10/SP98",
                "address": "26 Chemin de Sainte-Marthe",
                "update": "2019-12-01T05:00:00+00:00",
                "price_gazole": 1.51,
                "price_sp98": 1.67
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    5.37430169143,
                    43.3177505955
                ]
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2019-12-01T05:00:00+00:00"
        },
        {
            "datasetid": "prix_des_carburants_j_7",
            "recordid": "97e94cb107435765058f19d7dda1e9ed225569d3",
            "fields": {
                "city": "MARSEILLE",
                "automate_24_24": "Non",
                "price_e10": 1.639,
                "pop": "R",
                "timetable": "{\"Dimanche\": {\"fermeture\": \"21.00\", \"ouvert\": 1, \"ouverture\": \"07.00\"}, \"Jeudi\": {\"fermeture\": \"21.00\", \"ouvert\": 1, \"ouverture\": \"06.30\"}, \"Lundi\": {\"fermeture\": \"21.00\", \"ouvert\": 1, \"ouverture\": \"06.30\"}, \"Mardi\": {\"fermeture\": \"21.00\", \"ouvert\": 1, \"ouverture\": \"06.30\"}, \"Mercredi\": {\"fermeture\": \"21.00\", \"ouvert\": 1, \"ouverture\": \"06.30\"}, \"Samedi\": {\"fermeture\": \"21.00\", \"ouvert\": 1, \"ouverture\": \"07.00\"}, \"Vendredi\": {\"fermeture\": \"21.00\", \"ouvert\": 1, \"ouverture\": \"06.30\"}}",
                "services": "Boutique alimentaire/Station de gonflage/Boutique non alimentaire/DAB (Distributeur automatique de billets)/Lavage automatique/Lavage manuel/Wifi/Automate CB 24/24",
                "shortage": "SP95/GPLc",
                "cp": "13012",
                "id": "13012027",
                "fuel": "E10/SP98",
                "address": "67 AVENUE DES CAILLOLS",
                "update": "2022-01-02T08:59:37+00:00",
                "price_e85": 0.739,
                "price_gazole": 1.567,
                "price_sp98": 1.736
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2022-01-02T08:59:37+00:00"
        },
        {
            "datasetid": "prix_des_carburants_j_7",
            "recordid": "8647c6e98dadfc5c3e73705e649c139c479c519e",
            "fields": {
                "city": "MARSEILLE",
                "automate_24_24": "Non",
                "price_e10": 1.759,
                "pop": "R",
                "timetable": "{\"Dimanche\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Jeudi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Lundi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Mardi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Mercredi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Samedi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Vendredi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}}",
                "services": "Carburant additivé/DAB (Distributeur automatique de billets)/Automate CB 24/24",
                "shortage": "GPLc/SP95/SP98",
                "cp": "13009",
                "id": "13009001",
                "fuel": "E85/E10",
                "address": "Avenue de Lattre de Tassigny",
                "update": "2022-02-04T05:17:13+00:00",
                "price_e85": 0.809,
                "price_gazole": 1.699
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2022-02-04T05:17:13+00:00"
        },
        {
            "datasetid": "prix_des_carburants_j_7",
            "recordid": "ab7f033ccc76f9a2ec2c89003cce17ad130b6e87",
            "fields": {
                "price_sp95": 1.789,
                "city": "MARSEILLE",
                "automate_24_24": "Oui",
                "pop": "R",
                "timetable": "{\"Dimanche\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Jeudi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Lundi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Mardi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Mercredi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Samedi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Vendredi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}}",
                "services": "Carburant additivé/Vente de gaz domestique (Butane, Propane)/DAB (Distributeur automatique de billets)",
                "cp": "13012",
                "id": "13012024",
                "fuel": "Gazole/SP95/SP98",
                "address": "120 rue saint jean du desert",
                "update": "2022-01-31T17:47:58+00:00",
                "price_gazole": 1.655,
                "price_sp98": 1.789
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2022-01-31T17:47:58+00:00"
        },
        {
            "datasetid": "prix_des_carburants_j_7",
            "recordid": "f0d1df503d0a9388739b61d1b472a206481f2989",
            "fields": {
                "geo_point": [
                    43.29755,
                    5.49654
                ],
                "city": "MARSEILLE",
                "automate_24_24": "Non",
                "price_e10": 1.26,
                "timetable": "{\"Mardi\": {\"ouverture\": \"01.00\", \"fermeture\": \"01.00\", \"ouvert\": 0}, \"Samedi\": {\"ouverture\": \"01.00\", \"fermeture\": \"01.00\", \"ouvert\": 0}, \"Vendredi\": {\"ouverture\": \"01.00\", \"fermeture\": \"01.00\", \"ouvert\": 0}, \"Jeudi\": {\"ouverture\": \"01.00\", \"fermeture\": \"01.00\", \"ouvert\": 0}, \"Lundi\": {\"ouverture\": \"01.00\", \"fermeture\": \"01.00\", \"ouvert\": 0}, \"Dimanche\": {\"ouverture\": \"01.00\", \"fermeture\": \"01.00\", \"ouvert\": 0}, \"Mercredi\": {\"ouverture\": \"01.00\", \"fermeture\": \"01.00\", \"ouvert\": 0}}",
                "services": "Boutique alimentaire/Vente de gaz domestique (Butane, Propane)/DAB (Distributeur automatique de billets)/Automate CB 24/24",
                "name": "sarl camoins distribution",
                "brand": "Carrefour Contact",
                "pop": "R",
                "shortage": "E85/GPLc/SP95",
                "cp": "13011",
                "id": "13011015",
                "fuel": "E10",
                "address": "73 Route des Camoins",
                "update": "2020-05-27T08:46:27+00:00",
                "price_gazole": 1.179,
                "price_sp98": 1.36
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    5.49654,
                    43.29755
                ]
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2020-05-27T08:46:27+00:00"
        },
        {
            "datasetid": "prix_des_carburants_j_7",
            "recordid": "b92672c4870f8b4b9847f8051814c8ba356f5fd7",
            "fields": {
                "geo_point": [
                    43.3354,
                    5.40006
                ],
                "city": "MARSEILLE",
                "automate_24_24": "Oui",
                "price_e10": 1.767,
                "pop": "R",
                "timetable": "{\"Dimanche\": {\"fermeture\": \"22.00\", \"ouvert\": 1, \"ouverture\": \"06.00\"}, \"Jeudi\": {\"fermeture\": \"22.00\", \"ouvert\": 1, \"ouverture\": \"06.00\"}, \"Lundi\": {\"fermeture\": \"22.00\", \"ouvert\": 1, \"ouverture\": \"06.00\"}, \"Mardi\": {\"fermeture\": \"22.00\", \"ouvert\": 1, \"ouverture\": \"06.00\"}, \"Mercredi\": {\"fermeture\": \"22.00\", \"ouvert\": 1, \"ouverture\": \"06.00\"}, \"Samedi\": {\"fermeture\": \"22.00\", \"ouvert\": 1, \"ouverture\": \"06.00\"}, \"Vendredi\": {\"fermeture\": \"22.00\", \"ouvert\": 1, \"ouverture\": \"06.00\"}}",
                "services": "Carburant additivé/Boutique alimentaire/Station de gonflage/Boutique non alimentaire/Vente de gaz domestique (Butane, Propane)/Lavage automatique",
                "brand": "Avia",
                "name": "AVIA",
                "shortage": "E85/GPLc/SP95",
                "cp": "13014",
                "id": "13014010",
                "fuel": "Gazole/E10/SP98",
                "address": "33 Avenue Alexandre Ansaldi",
                "update": "2022-02-05T05:00:00+00:00",
                "price_gazole": 1.719,
                "price_sp98": 1.852
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    5.40006,
                    43.3354
                ]
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2022-02-05T05:00:00+00:00"
        },
        {
            "datasetid": "prix_des_carburants_j_7",
            "recordid": "b41206764c94111be7fb621c40882e0e22a31b11",
            "fields": {
                "fuel": "Gazole/E10",
                "address": "95 Avenue des Roches",
                "update": "2021-09-20T04:00:00+00:00",
                "city": "MARSEILLE",
                "price_e10": 1.659,
                "services": "Carburant additivé/Toilettes publiques/Boutique alimentaire/Station de gonflage/Vente de gaz domestique (Butane, Propane)/Lavage manuel",
                "price_gazole": 1.559,
                "pop": "R",
                "shortage": "SP95/E85",
                "cp": "13007",
                "id": "13007007"
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2021-09-20T04:00:00+00:00"
        },
        {
            "datasetid": "prix_des_carburants_j_7",
            "recordid": "80249cc9c4d32d7609225c509e4c28dca8c2cf94",
            "fields": {
                "geo_point": [
                    43.3847,
                    5.35854
                ],
                "city": "MARSEILLE",
                "automate_24_24": "Oui",
                "price_e10": 1.715,
                "pop": "R",
                "timetable": "{\"Dimanche\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Jeudi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Lundi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Mardi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Mercredi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Samedi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}, \"Vendredi\": {\"ouvert\": 1}}",
                "brand": "Esso Express",
                "name": "ESSO N.D. LIMITE",
                "shortage": "SP95",
                "cp": "13015",
                "id": "13015004",
                "fuel": "Gazole/E10/SP98",
                "address": "437 Avenue de Saint-Antoine",
                "update": "2022-02-07T18:13:00+00:00",
                "price_gazole": 1.675,
                "price_sp98": 1.794
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    5.35854,
                    43.3847
                ]
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2022-02-07T18:13:00+00:00"
        },
        {
            "datasetid": "prix_des_carburants_j_7",
            "recordid": "6853e28e086220c8deb594146373628f9c3c62c8",
            "fields": {
                "fuel": "Gazole/E10/SP98",
                "address": "32 BOULEVARD SCHLOESING",
                "update": "2022-02-06T23:01:00+00:00",
                "city": "MARSEILLE",
                "price_e10": 1.706,
                "pop": "R",
                "services": "Restauration à emporter/Carburant additivé/Boutique alimentaire/Station de gonflage/Boutique non alimentaire/Vente de gaz domestique (Butane, Propane)/DAB (Distributeur automatique de billets)/Lavage automatique/Lavage manuel",
                "price_gazole": 1.659,
                "shortage": "E85/GPLc/SP95",
                "cp": "13009",
                "id": "13009008",
                "price_sp98": 1.814
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2022-02-06T23:01:00+00:00"
        }
    ],
    "facet_groups": [
        {
            "name": "city",
            "facets": [
                {
                    "name": "MARSEILLE",
                    "count": 72,
                    "state": "refined",
                    "path": "MARSEILLE"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I wrap this json in let json =  """ """

And i try to decode in playground like this :

```
import Foundation

struct Hits : Decodable {
 
    
    let nhits : Int
    let parameters : Parameters
    let records : [Records]
    let facetGroups : [FacetGroup]
}

struct Parameters : Decodable {
    let dataset : String
    let q : String
    let rows : Int
    let start : Int
    let refine : Refine
    let format : String
    let timezone : String
}

struct Refine : Decodable {
    let city : String
}

struct Records : Decodable {
    let datasetid : String
    let recordid : String
    let fields : Fields?
    let geometry : Geometry?
    let recordTimestamp : String
}

struct Fields : Decodable {
    let geoPoint : [Int]?
    let priceSp95 : Double?
    let city : String
    let automate2424 : String?
    let priceE10 : Double?
    let services : String?
    let name : String?
    let timetable : String?
    let brand  : String?
    let pop : String
    let cp : String
    let id : String
    let fuel : String
    let address : String
    let update : String
    let priceGazole : Double?
  
}

struct Geometry : Decodable {
    let type : String
    let coordinates : [Int]
}

struct FacetGroup : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let facets : [Facets]
}

struct Facets : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let count : Int
    let state : String
    let path : String
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
decoder.dataDecodingStrategy = .deferredToData

let launch = try decoder.decode(Hits.self, from: Data(json.utf8))
```

and console returns this error :

Playground execution terminated: An error was thrown and was not caught:
▿ DecodingError
▿ dataCorrupted : Context
- codingPath : 0 elements
- debugDescription : "The given data was not valid JSON."
▿ underlyingError : Optional
- some : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around line 23, column 18." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around line 23, column 18., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=446}

i found that problem is due to "timetable" object. if i remove it the json is valid. But i need this object...

my question is : do you know please how i can modify this to have a valid json ?

i hope this is clear.

thank you in advance.

Comment: It's because of the escaped quotes, `\"`, you get the error. Replace them with normal quotes `"` to make it work in your playground

Comment: thank you joakim, so the goal is to have "{Dimanche: {ouvert: 1}, Jeudi: {ouvert: 1}, Lundi: {ouvert: 1}, Mardi: {ouvert: 1}, Mercredi: {ouvert: 1}, Samedi: {ouvert: 1}, Vendredi: {ouvert: 1}}" ? 
i tryed with replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "") 
but the result is : {"Dimanche": {"ouvert": 1}, "Jeudi": {"ouvert": 1}, "Lundi": {"ouvert": 1}, "Mardi": {"ouvert": 1}, "Mercredi": {"ouvert": 1}, "Samedi": {"ouvert": 1}, "Vendredi": {"ouvert": 1}}

Comment: No you don't do that with swift code. Use Find & Replace in Xcode or some other Text editor to fix the string once and for all.

Comment: If you replace `\"` with `\\\"` I guess it should work then, or use `#` before and and after the triple quote enlosing

Comment: oh yes you are right, but this playground is an exemple. in the application that i want to create, there is a call to api rest that return a json with this format. so i need a solution (function) that modifying the json returned by calling api.
sorry for my english and thank you.

Comment: If you get the response from the API, then it should be fine. It's because you printed the value, and then it showed only one backslash. But in fact, there are three backslash behind the hood.

Comment: To illustrate, you can use this in playground: `let strTest = "{\"Dimanche\": {\"ouvert\": 1} }"; print(strTest); let strTest2 = "{\\\"Dimanche\\\": {\\\"ouvert\\\": 1} }"; print(strTest2)` and check the output.

Comment: ok ok i understand that

Comment: it's work on my application. thank you for your help. have a good day